# Which character encoding needs to be used for Javadoc options files?

Tags: java, javadoc

Javadoc supports options files to be used like the following:

```
javadoc @optsFile1 @optsFile2 @optsFile3
```

The format of that files doesn't seem to be [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html) too much:

> The arguments within a file can be space-separated or newline-separated. If a file name contains embedded spaces, then put the whole file name in double quotation marks.

Additionally I found the following sentence:

> The -encoding option is used for encoding the files read by the javadoc tool, while the -docencoding and -charset options are used for encoding the files written by the tool.

That reads like the value given for the option `-encoding` is the same used for reading options files. But `-encoding` itself documents the following:

> Specifies the encoding name of the source files, such as EUCJIS/SJIS.

That sentence explicitly mentions sources files only, which the options files don't necessarily need to count to. Another problem is that this argument might only be available within an option file, so Javadoc might not know in theory.

I would have expected instead that those options files are always read with some encoding just to be sure, something like `UTF-8` or the platform default encoding used as fallback in other charset-related places well. But in the end, this doesn't seem to be explicitly documented anywhere, even though especially the platform default encoding might differ between use cases.

**So, which character encoding needs to be used for Javadoc options files?**

Thanks!

Comment: `optsFile1` is a "file read by the javadoc tool", so the `-encoding` applies to read it. If you don't specify an encoding, the default encoding is used. Seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: *"The problem is that this argument might only be available within an option file"* Why would that be? File cannot generally self-describe their own encoding (e.g. XML files is an exemption to that), so encoding must generally be specified outside the file. `javadoc` is just like all other programs reading text files.